# Writing own LDAP controller in php

Tags: php, ldap

to centralize my address books I'm thinking of doing that via a LDAP service. As I haven't found a free service somewhere, I guess i have to implement this on my own.

So the basic idea is to implement a search (which is restricted to contacts only) and a small filtering capability. The search looks the records up in an backend mysql database. Pretty strait forward. All other functionalities like add, remove, edit, etc, are not supported (in first place - maybe never, don't know how restricted I am through the http protocol).

Does anyone know how the binding and search operation look like on the service, I've only found material how they are handled by client...

If someone know a free service (in php) that can be used on my public webserver, I would prefer not doing all the implementation work ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). Zend has a built-in class for [LDAP services](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.ldap.html). We use the class at work for authentication into our web-based admin applications.

Comment: +1 for the framework. I had to write my own back in 2001 and it sucked big time. If a framework had been around back then I would have jumped on it in a second.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As far as I read the manual their component allows to access an existing LDAP service (like AD, etc...). I'm looking for a framework that simulates a LDAP service and allows me have a custom backend (in my case I'd prefer an mysql server)